# Xamarin iOS button width change according to text

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a multi-lingual app and text size can vary according to language.

What i am trying to achieve is resize the button according to space text has taken. Text will only be a one word so width of button will never become so large that it goes out of the screen boundaries.

Is there a way in Xamarin iOS to do it ?

Comment: How is your UI made, in code or Storyboards? And can you show it

Comment: UI is made in Storyboards

Comment: Can you show the storyboard the constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just doing something like this:

```
var button = new UIButton();
button.SetTitle("Some text", UIControlState.Normal);
button.SizeToFit();
View.AddSubview(button);
```